# Spark SQL(PySpark) - SparkSession import Error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to execute a simple Spark SQL code (PySpark) using Spark-Submit but received the below error. Note - I am running this in Spark 2.x.

spark-submit HousePriceSolution.py

**Error:**

> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>   ImportError: cannot import name SparkSession

**Code:**

```
 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
 PRICE_SQ_FT = "Price SQ Ft"

 if __name__ == "__main__":

  session = SparkSession.builder.appName("HousePriceSolution").getOrCreate()    
  realEstate = session.read \
  .option("header","true") \
  .option("inferSchema", value=True) \
  .csv("hdfs:............./RealEstate.csv")

  realEstate.groupBy("Location") \
  .avg(PRICE_SQ_FT) \
  .orderBy("avg(Price SQ FT)") \
  .show()
  session.stop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the `spark-submit` is pointing to another version of spark. Check what version of spark is used by `spark-submit` using the following command:

```
spark-submit --version
```

If the spark-version is ok, then check what the `PYTHONPATH` contains (`echo $PYTHONPATH`), because it is posible that `PYTHONPATH` has the pyspark library from another version of spark. If `PYTHONPATH` doesn't contain the pyspark library, then add to it like this:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:"$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/*"
```